# spine.js populate model instances at start up

Tags: javascript, spine.js

Absolute beginner here. I want to load data into models as soon as the page loads.
Before anything else is executed. At the moment I have this code.

```
// Model code
var Portfolio = Spine.Model.sub({});
Portfolio.configure("Portfolio")

Portfolio.extend({
  populate: function(values){
    for(var i in values[0]){
     // add attributes to Model
      this.attributes.push(i);
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++ ){
      var tmpInst =  this.create(values[j]);
      tmpInst.save();
    }
  }
});

// app controller code
$(function(){
   var App =Spine.Controller.sub({
    init: function(){
      jQuery.getJSON("../xml/data.json", 
        function(result){ 
             Portfolio.populate(result['content']);
        }
      ).complete(function(result) { 
          // do other stuff
      });
    }
  })
    var app = new App();
});
```

So when the page has finished loading the controller `init` function is called, which retrieves the json data and passes it to the Model which parses it and creates the individual instances.

Am I doing this wrong? I have seen Fetch function in the documentation but with no example of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Spine's framework to do this:

1. Instead of firing your own jQuery.getJSON(), include Spine.Ajax in your Model.

   ```
   Portfolio.extend(Spine.Model.Ajax);
   ```
2. Set the Spine.Model.host to your server
3. Add url attribute/method to your Portfolio object to something like 'xml/data.json'
4. Call Portfolio.fetch()
5. Override Portfolio.fetch() function to extract just the node of array data or whatever initialization you had in mind just like the configure. If I am not mistaken, fetch() will load the objects and set all the attributes provided in the JSON even if they are not configured in Model @configure call

Comment: Thanks Alon....I moved over to backbone in the end. I got fed up with all the code examples being written in coffee script.